# How can I update a text file using batch script which will be triggered by VB Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

The challenge here is, the batch script is triggered using Vb script and the text file is created using the same VBScript.

The text file name contains a variable in it. I am able to pass the variable from VBS to batch, but unable to append the same text file.

VBScript :

```
Dim wsh
Set wsh = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strinputa = "102590"
wsh.run "Test.bat " + chr(34) + strinputa + chr(34)
set wsh = nothing
```

Batch script :

```
Set Rid = %1
Xcopy "Location 1" "Location 2" /s /e /k /i >> %~dp0Logs\log_%Rid%.txt
pause
```

Keep in mind that there is already have a text file in "\Logs" folder with file name 
'log_102590', which I want to update.

Comment: This is not VB.net

Comment: Try with `set "Rid=%~1`, remove the spaces around the `=`-sign as the become part of the variable name and value otherwise. Anyway, why do you do such a complicated way, why using a batch file for copying, rather than copy the file in VBScript immediately?

Comment: Thank you very much. "Rid=%~1" works just fine. I am using batch file to copy because I felt it a bit easy to copy files to network drive, unlike vbscript.